# Json giving error

Tags: javascript, json

My code

```
function getUIContent(){
    alert('hi');
    var jsn = '{"channels":[{"name":"video1","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video2","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video3","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},'+
    ']}';
}
```

Now i want to access the name of the channel

I tried like

```
var channels = jsn.channels[0].name;
alert(channels);
```

But it is giving error. I also want to know how to get the length of the channels.

I am new to javascript development. I tried a lot but i didn't got the answer.

Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, there is a `,` before the `]` that is causing the error

Comment: @LightStyle I think that OP have forgotten to parse the string as well. But you know `[1,];` is legal syntax in modern browsers.

Comment: Yes, he forgot to use `JSON.parse`. JSLint gives me an error.

Comment: I don't understand @Priya anyway, is your JSON static or is it retrieved by an AJAX request?

Comment: *"But it is giving error"* Please tell us more about the error.

Comment: it is a static json @LightStyle

Comment: Well there is no need to use JSON! Just remove the `'` before and after that string, so it will become a simple JS object and you can access it as you were already doing! See @MeLight's answer, it will simplify your life a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the last ',' to make it valid JSON:

```
  var jsn = '{"channels":[{"name":"video1","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video2","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video3","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"}'+
             ']}';
```

Edit:/
Of course you have to use JSON.parse before using this string
Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/4j3Rh/

Comment: This is still an invalid JSON !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Please explain, JsonLint validates after removing the comma.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox I think he wrote that because you're using the JSON as string. If you do it like that, you have to use JSON.parse to make it a real JSON object. See the code in my fiddle for a working example.

Comment: @schlingel: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). JSON is a data exchange format, like XML, CSV or YAML. It can only exist in JavaScript in form of a string. People tend to confuse object literals with JSON, but they are completely different things.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot: It's valid JSON (at least the string content). See my previous comment. The whole code snippet is JavaScript of course.

Answer (score 6):

You must remove the leading and tailing `'` marks, so that your JSON becomes an object and not a string. And as others have mentioned remove the last comma `,`.

So instead of this:

```
var jsn = '{"channels":[{"name":"video1","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video2","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video3","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},'+
    ']}';
```

You have this:

```
var jsn = {"channels":[{"name":"video1","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video2","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video3","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"}]};
```

Comment: Very useful to have a string inside a list of channels ;) `'+ '`

Comment: *"You must remove the leading and tailing `'` marks, so that your JSON becomes actually a JSON and not a string."* That is incorrect. JSON is a textual data-exchange format, like XML, CSV or YAML. It can *only* exist in JavaScript in form of a string. If you remove the quotation marks, you have an object literal, not JSON. See also http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/. Of course using an object literal makes more sense than parsing a JSON string in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have a tailing `,` (comma) at the end of the `{}` (object).

It should be:

```
var jsn = '{"channels":[{"name":"video1","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video2","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video3","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"}'+
                 ']}';
```

Comment: It's an object not a map. Even if the handling is similar.

Answer (score 1):

First, the json object is in valid.

```
{
    "channels": [
        {
            "name": "video1",
            "image": "images/bodyguard.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "video2",
            "image": "images/bodyguard.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "video3",
            "image": "images/bodyguard.jpg"
        }, //   <-------------remove this comma

    ]
}
```

Second, at this point this is a Json String, it must be deserialized into an object so that we can access the its properties using the `.` notation. This can be accomplished as using the `JSON.parse()` method which is included in most modern browsers.

`var obj = JSON.parse(jsn);`

Then access the properties from the object as follows:

```
var size = obj.channels.length;
```

During your journey in Javascript development if you experience any more JSON errors you may want to use the [JsonLint tool](http://jsonlint.com/), which allows you to validate your json by copying and pasting it into the website.

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3v2z3/

Answer (score -1):

try the below,

```
var jsn = '{"channels":[{"name":"video1","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video2","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"},{"name":"video3","image":"images/bodyguard.jpg"}]}'; 

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsn); //If jquery used [or]

var obj = JSON.parse(jsn);

alert(obj.channels[0]["name"]);
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for such a simple operation?

Comment: Yes, for this, it wont needed. But,It would be helpful to proceed with parsing huge data's..

Comment: It is not true, parseJSON uses `JSON.parse` internally and, in case it is not defined, it uses a very simple conversion process. Taken directly from jQuery 1.9.1's source: http://pastebin.com/y6S0dtR1